# How do I keep the user from closing the window?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to try to make an "unclosable" HTML page.

```
function pass(){ 
var ansf=prompt ("Password Required", "Password");
if (ansf=="asjdfhasdijf") alert("Password Accepted");
else (pass());
}
```

The HTML involved with this looks like this:

```
<body onUnload="pass()">
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working, it used to (about 1 year ago).

I apologize if this is a stupid question, I haven't worked with JavaScript for at least a year (and even then I knew very little).

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/qmfMd/1/.

Comment: `Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs []` Current browser design will never allow an "unclosable page"

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't really work. Plus, if you actually made my browser uncloseable, I'd make your server go away.

Comment: This was just for kicks and giggles. You can also easily close this with Task Manager...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will work if you do this:

```
function pass(){ 

    var ansf=prompt ("Password Required", "Password");
    if (ansf=="asjdfhasdijf") alert("Password Accepted");
    else (pass());

}
window.onbeforeunload = pass;
```

Here's a demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/khxM7/** I've made it easy to exit if anyone is worried.

Comment: All I did was click the box that said "prevent this site from creating more dialogs" ;)

Comment: you've got to be kidding me... what will they think of next 9_9

Comment: This is blocked by modern browsers. How do you fix it? Make an actual function, and make another function that just runs `setTimeout(actualFunction, 1)`. Set `window.onbeforeunload = callActualFunction;` and that way it'll work...

Comment: Also to bypass `prevent this site from creating more dialogs`, use a `window.open` and set the `href` to something like `javascript:document.write("<h1>Your single line only HTML</h1>")`. You can try to communicate using `window.opener`...